# Ruby savon : provide operations empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

i am new in ruby and rails i want to send a soap request using "savon" gem but it provide operations empty when i run this client.operations, here is my code 
I am using Savon 2.3.0
ruby 2.1.0

Here is documentation of savon 2.3.0
http://rubydoc.info/gems/savon/frames

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'https://webservice.kareo.com/services/soap/2.1/KareoServices.svc?wsdl',
                 :ssl_verify_mode => :none,
                 log: true,
                 pretty_print_xml: true) 
puts client.operations
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need that. Try to call a function from your service. If that doesn't work then download SoapUI and try to create a successful call from SoapUI to your service.
In a next step you build ruby code which creates the same request as the one from SoapUI.
If that doesn't work for your come back and ask again.